# Removing gap to the left of the insert fields as well as the gap between the two buttons?

Tags: asp.net, detailsview

`<asp:DetailsView ID="dtl_people" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="personID" DataSourceID="dsrc_peopleObject"  DefaultMode="Insert" CssClass="table-bordered table-striped" ControlStyle-Width="50%" ControlStyle-Height="200px" OnPageIndexChanging="dtl_people_PageIndexChanging" RowStyle-Wrap="False">
<FieldHeaderStyle Width="15%" />
<Fields>
<asp:BoundField DataField="personID" HeaderText="personID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="personID" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="lastName" HeaderText="lastName" SortExpression="lastName" ControlStyle-Width="100%">
 </asp:BoundField>
<asp:BoundField DataField="firstName" HeaderText="firstName" SortExpression="firstName" />
 <asp:BoundField DataField="address" HeaderText="address" SortExpression="address" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="phone" HeaderText="phone" SortExpression="phone" ItemStyle-Width="350px">
<ItemStyle Width="350px"></ItemStyle>
</asp:BoundField>
<asp:CommandField ShowInsertButton="True" ButtonType="Button"  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-Wrap="False" />
</Fields>
<InsertRowStyle Wrap="true"/>
 </asp:DetailsView>`[image]

I want to remove gap between buttons and also gap to the left of field where you enter details,thank you

Comment: Please add a razor code you are using into question then simple css from margin will do it.

Comment: Fix up your images and add code to show your problem or this will quickly be deleted.

Comment: it will be easy to help, if you provide your code for this design what ever you tried?

Comment: Entered Code of DetailsView

Answer (score 0):

The dafult behavior of the ASP.NET `DetailsView` control is to display data in a tabular fashion with ***no padding applied***.This means that you have a CSS style rule somewhere which causes this undesired behavior.

Luckily this is pretty easy to find:

1. Run your web application in Google Chrome.
2. Press Ctrl+Shift+I to open up the developer console.
3. Click on the Elements tab.
4. Right click on the element in the page where the spacing issue is happening and click **Inspect**
5. Look carefully through the **Styles** section in the developer console for the style rule that causes the undesired effects and make the necessary changes in the style sheet file to remove it.

**Example:**
[image: Inspecting CSS style rules in Google Chrome]